# onclick listener on listview without normal id

Tags: android, listview

I have this code for create a  custom listadapter 
this is a part of my code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String success)
{
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (context, jsonList,
            R.layout.items, new String[]{TAG_PELI, TAG_nombre2},
            new int[]{R.id.nombrePeli, R.id.nombreTwo});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView();
}
```

in my xml witht custom listview is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>
```

the problem is that at call "onclicklistener" the id is not defined because is declared with
android:id="@android:id/list", I have to choose this form because thrown an error. what have I to call "oncliclistener". thanks

EDIT =============================== (SOLVED)

with this code works for me! :) Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Context context;
private static String url ="http://comupunt.esy.es/cities.php";
private static final String TAG_PELI = "name";
private static final String TAG_nombre2 = "nametwo";

ListView list;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
list =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
new GetJSONActivity(MainActivity.this).execute();
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    HashMap<String,String> map =  
   (HashMap<String,String>)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String value = map.get(TAG_PELI);
    String products = map.get(TAG_nombre2);
    Toast toast1 =
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast1.show();
}
});
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

return true;
}

private class GetJSONActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
private Activity activity;
public GetJSONActivity(Activity activity)
{
this.activity = activity;
context = activity;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        JSONArray json = jparser.GetJSONfromUrl(url);
        for(int i =0;i <json.length();i++){
            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String vpeli = c.getString(TAG_PELI);
                String vname2 = c.getString(TAG_nombre2);
                HashMap <String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put(TAG_PELI, vpeli);
                map.put(TAG_nombre2, vname2);
                jsonList.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "error creando variables";
            }
        }
    ;   }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return "exito";
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(String success)
{
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (context, jsonList,
        R.layout.items, new String[]{TAG_PELI, TAG_nombre2},
        new int[]{R.id.nombrePeli, R.id.nombreTwo});
list.setAdapter(adapter);   

}


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign an id to your `ListView` in your `xml` file :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list_id"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>
```

and in your java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
private Context context;
private static String url ="http://comupunt.esy.es/cities.php";
private static final String TAG_PELI = "name";
private static final String TAG_nombre2 = "nametwo";

ListView listView;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
listView = findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
new GetJSONActivity(MainActivity.this).execute();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

private class GetJSONActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
private Activity activity;
public GetJSONActivity(Activity activity)
{
this.activity = activity;
context = activity;
}
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
        try{
            JSONArray json = jparser.GetJSONfromUrl(url);
            for(int i =0;i <json.length();i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vpeli = c.getString(TAG_PELI);
                    String vname2 = c.getString(TAG_nombre2);
                    HashMap <String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    map.put(TAG_PELI, vpeli);
                    map.put(TAG_nombre2, vname2);
                    jsonList.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "error creando variables";
                }
            }
        ;   }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return "exito";
}
protected void onPostExecute(String success)
{
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (context, jsonList,
            R.layout.items, new String[]{TAG_PELI, TAG_nombre2},
            new int[]{R.id.nombrePeli, R.id.nombreTwo});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

}
}
```

now your list has a valid id and you can use it like this : `R.id.my_list_id`

Comment: I have that, but it throw a same error, your content must have a listview whose atributte is android.R.id.list

Comment: it's because you are using `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` . you should use `Activity` or `Fragment` and define your `ListView` in that.

Comment: but it isn't compatible with other methods. new GetJSONActivity(MainActivity.this).execute(); setListAdapter(adapter); getListView();

Answer (score 0):

Use your own app-specific ID in your XML, references using the "add to" syntax of `@+id`:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Then you can references it in code as `R.id.list`.

=== Edit

Ok, I see what you are doing now, though you're not actually hooking up a listener.  You should be able to do this:

```
getListView().setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then your `Activity` just implements the `onClick()` method appropriately (though I'm not sure that's really what you're trying to do here.)

Comment: sorry, but I don't undestand how I have to do is, can you explain me into the code? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment.  Using the app specific ID is the "normal" way of using IDs for your layouts.  It will not affect other usage in adapter, etc.

Comment: yes, but I have to use android:id="@android:id/list" because I am using a class with extends ListActivity

Comment: Without seeing code I can't say why you would need this; but, it shouldn't not be an issue to use a custom ID.